# Use of shadowed object variables give unexpected and unexplained results

Tags: java, attributes

```java
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super s = new Sub();
        System.out.println(s.a); //Super-Attribut
        System.out.println(s.m1()); //Sub-Attribut
        System.out.println(new Sub().m2()); //Super-Attribut
    }
}

class Super {
    String a = "Super-Attribut";

    String m1() {
        return a;
    }

    String x() {
        return a;
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    String a = "Sub-Attribut";

    String m1() {
        return a;
    }

    String m2() {
        return x();
    }
}
```

I have a question regarding the above code, especially the line `System.out.println(new Sub().m2())`. In this line an instance of the class `Sub` is created. On this instance the function `m2()` in the class `Sub` is called. The method `m2()` in `Sub` calls the method `x()` in `Super`. The method `x()` returns the string variable `a`.

Shouldn't this `a` be the `a`, which is declared in the class `Sub`, since an object of the class `Sub` is being used, i.e the runtime type is `Sub`, and also the declaration type or the static type of the used object, which is `new Sub()`, is `Sub`?

Comment: Field access calls are not covered by [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). This is justified since a field that hides a superclass-field could have a different type (in the example: `Sub.a` could be, for example, an `int`). From `Super::x`'s point of view, the only visible field `a` is `Super.a`. --- Those effects are the reason we should try to avoid hiding fields.

Comment: If `Super` gets an implicit reference to `this`, when `Sub` or `m2()` calls `Super` or `x()`, then `x()` in `Super` should know on which object to operate?

Comment: Again: the field `Sub.a` hiding `Super.a` could be, for example, of type `int`. This would break method `x()`. Of course Java could have the semantics that if the field hiding a superclass-field has the same or assignment-compatible type, then this field is used. But Java hasn't. And it would make this already confusing construct even more confusing.

Comment: I can't get my head around the rules here...